# Best practice for double every column on the same DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

### I want to take a DF and double each column (with new column name).

I want to make "Stress Tests" on my ML Model (implemented using PySpark & Spark Pipeline) and see how well it performs if I double/triple the number of features in my input dataset.

For Example, take this DF:

```
+-------+-------+-----+------+
|    _c0|    _c1|  _c2|   _c3|
+-------+-------+-----+------+
|   1   |Testing|     | true |
+-------+-------+-----+------+
```

and make it like this:

```
+-------+-------+-----+------+-------+-------+-----+------+
|    _c0|    _c1|  _c2|   _c3|    _c4|    _c5|  _c6|   _c7|
+-------+-------+-----+------+-------+-------+-----+------+
|   1   |Testing|     | true |   1   |Testing|     | true |
+-------+-------+-----+------+-------+-------+-----+------+
```

**The easiest way I can do it is like this:**

```
df = df
doubledDF = df
for col in df.columns:
    doubledDF = doubledDF.withColumn(col+"1dup", df[col])
```

However, it takes way to much time.

I would appreciate any solution, and even more the explanation why this solution approach is better.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not aware of pyspark equivalent.. but in scala I would do df.select()... with column names using alias and without alias.. this way it will have columns repeated without calling withColumn... eg `df.select(col("_c0"),col("_c0").as("_c0_dup"),col("_c0"),col("_c1").as("_c1_dup"))`

Comment: Thank you. But I need a more general solution. To take a 1300 columns DF and make it a 2600 columns DF.

Comment: @Harelz check the execution plans between your method and the answer below (`df.explain()`) - they probably do the same thing under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using [`selectExpr()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr). The asterisk `*` will `un-list` a `list`.

For eg; `*['_c0', '_c1', '_c2', '_c3']` will return `'_c0', '_c1', '_c2', '_c3'`

Along with the help of [`list-comprehensions`](https://hackernoon.com/list-comprehension-in-python-8895a785550b), this code can be fairly generalized.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,'Testing','',True)],('_c0','_c1','_c2','_c3'))
df.show()
+---+-------+---+----+
|_c0|    _c1|_c2| _c3|
+---+-------+---+----+
|  1|Testing|   |true|
+---+-------+---+----+

col_names = df.columns
print(col_names)
['_c0', '_c1', '_c2', '_c3']

df = df.selectExpr(*[i for i in col_names],*[i+' as '+i+'_dup' for i in col_names])
df.show()
+---+-------+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|_c0|    _c1|_c2| _c3|_c0_dup|_c1_dup|_c2_dup|_c3_dup|
+---+-------+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1|Testing|   |true|      1|Testing|       |   true|
+---+-------+---+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**Note:** The following code will work too.

```
df = df.selectExpr('*',*[i+' as '+i+'_dup' for i in col_names])
```

Comment: If you can kindly un-accept this answer, I can delete it. I mis-understood your question. I read the comment by @undefined_variable to post an answer. This solution is no better than the one you are using at the moment.

Comment: Your code runs for me in 3 minutes, my code doesn't end after a whole hour. I know they are supposed to perform the same. but in reality your's is much better.

Comment: Well, I am a bit surprised. But, if it works for you, then it's fine. That said, my apologies for not taking a deep read on your question.

Comment: To be honest I'm happy you did not take a deep read on my question, otherwise you wouldn't have suggested this clean and awesome solution. Good Job!